# Testflight and watchOS2: app for apple watch is currently unavailable

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, ios9, watchos-2

I don't understand why I cant install my watch app via testflight. It just says app is installed on iphone but app for apple watch is currently unavailable. I can run everything in Xcode. Anyone had an issue like this?
(watchOS 2 beta 5)

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue. I guess all we can do is wait until beta 6.